# Moving from php4 to php5

Tags: php, migration

I tried moving to php5, I am getting into lot of issues. This class gives error :

```
 Class DatabaseConnection 
 {                              // error here
     private $connection;
     private $result;   
     // 
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->databaseName = $GLOBALS['configuration']['db'];
     }
     // other methods follow
 }
```

I have the following in the .htaccess file as well:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
php_value register_globals on
```

This is the error I get :

```
php5 error syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

Comment: That code snippet passes my validator error free. The problem must be in some other part than the one you've posted.

Comment: Nothing in that bit of code should cause an error

Comment: On an unrelated note, keywords in PHP aren't case sensitive, but should generally be lower-case ("class", rather than "Class"). This is unrelated because using a capitalized "Class" won't cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that PHP5 is working.